# How to conditionally do a recursive merge?

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to conditionally do a recursive merge.  That is, if a key exists in the second object, I'd like to use it to override values in the first.  For example, this does what I want:

```
$ echo '{"a":"value"}{"bar": {"a":"override"}}' | jq -sS '.[0] * if (.[1].foo|length) > 0 then .[1].foo else {} end'
{
  "a": "value"
}
$ echo '{"a":"value"}{"foo": {"a":"override"}}' | jq -sS '.[0] * if (.[1].foo|length) > 0 then .[1].foo else {} end'
{
  "a": "override"
}
```

In the first example, the second object does not contain a "foo" key, so the override does not happen.  In the 2nd example, the second object does contain "foo", so the value is changed.  (In my actual use, I always have 3 objects on the input and sometimes have a 4th which may override some of the previous values.)

Although the above works, it seems absurdly ugly.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I imagine something like `jq -sS '.[0] * (.[1].foo ? .[1].foo : {})` or similar.

Comment: Where does the "foo" selection criterion come from? The command-line? Or is it supposed to be hard-wired into the program?

Comment: The key will come from the command line. (And passed into the jq and be hard-wired into the jq program, I suppose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-n` flag specified on the command line this should do the trick:

```
reduce inputs as $in (input; . * ($in.foo // {}))
```

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y4NLeM7Obf)</sup>